# How to change color of line with colorpicker JavaFx?

Tags: javafx

I click on colorpicker, choose the color, and it must change color of the next line, how to do that? I try like that, but it does not want to change color.

```
    final ColorPicker colorpicker = new ColorPicker();
                         color = colorpicker.getValue();
                         path.setStroke(color);
```

From colorpicker i get "web" view of color name, but path.setStroke(Color.web(color)) - does not work too.

Comment: This seems to work fine for me: can you show a complete example (e.g. as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?

Comment: Yeh, I tried right now put it in start function, it is working fine, but with button from scene builder doesnt want.